# Runnable not updating SeekBar in Music Player

Tags: android, runnable, android-seekbar

```
playb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song);
            player.start();
            playb.setClickable(false);
            seeksong.setMax(player.getDuration());
            new Thread(new SeekHandler()).start();
          }
    });
```

---

```
 SeekHandler extends MainActivity implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run() {
    while (player != null && player.getCurrentPosition() < player.getDuration()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        seeksong.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
    }
}
```

---

SeekBar is not updating to current song position.Please tell me correct way to do this.Also mention if any alternative way is available

Comment: Do you have solution on this ? Thanks in advance @ShadowGod